TensorFlow Federated Learning - Kernel CPU Error: Failed to run computation: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'PyFunc' used by
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gOhyS5kWL346FliLp2flzQbtmpqLTKIk?usp=sharing
I am trying to train breakhis data with federated avg. It computes up to
result = trainer.next(state, federated_train_data)

row. When it comes to this row, gives an error about kernel. I computed this dataset with CNN and got results. What is the problem can anyone help me?
